# MATLAB: Integrate one timetable into another

Tags: matlab, array-merge, timetable

I would like to expand an existing timetable. The original timetable consists of trading days only, while I would like to expand it to reflect all weekdays (no matter if working day or not).

Consider the original timetable `tt`. I would like to expand it using the `RowTimes`vector `datesWeekdays`. The expanded rows should contain NaNs.

When playing around, I was wondering if it makes sense to firstly create a new timetable comprising all dates and setting the data to NaN and subsequently "integrate" the original timetable `tt` into the new timetable `ttWeekdays`.

Here's a toy example:

```
data = rand(3,2);
dates = datetime({'2018-04-30', '2018-05-02', '2018-05-03'}, 'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd');
tt = array2timetable(data, 'RowTimes', dates, 'VariableNames', {'high', 'low'})

datesWeekdays = datetime({'2018-04-30', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-02', '2018-05-03', '2018-05-04'}, 'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd');
dataWeekdays = nan(5,2);
ttWeekdays = array2timetable(dataWeekdays, 'RowTimes', datesWeekdays, 'VariableNames', {'high', 'low'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`retime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/retime.html) for this. Something like this:

```
% Set up a date vector
newDates = datetime('2018-04-30'):datetime('2018-05-10');
newDates(isweekend(newDates)) = [];

% Use RETIME in default mode to expand input table
retime(tt, newDates)
```

which gets

```
  9×2 timetable
       Time         high        low  
    ___________    _______    _______
    30-Apr-2018    0.81472    0.91338
    01-May-2018        NaN        NaN
    02-May-2018    0.90579    0.63236
    03-May-2018    0.12699    0.09754
    04-May-2018        NaN        NaN
    07-May-2018        NaN        NaN
    08-May-2018        NaN        NaN
    09-May-2018        NaN        NaN
    10-May-2018        NaN        NaN
```

Note that `retime` supports a variety of methods for filling in the missing data - here we're using the default which is `'fillwithmissing'`.

Comment: That's great, because it is so easy ;-)